# all substrings of a specified length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a string column with variable length. I need to get all the substrings of the cell value with a specified length

Example:

```
094740
```

Statement:

```
select ???(Column, 3) from table
```

Result to be:

```
094
947
474
740
```

Can this be achieved without a stored procedure

Comment: Considering that it should be "without a stored procedure", can it be a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use CTE recursive with a simple math formula to make it.

CTE recursive will get a result set to represent how many row with offset by the statement

**Query 1**:

```
declare @offset int = 3
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT 0 startIndex, len(col) totalLen,col
   FROM T
   UNION ALL
   SELECT startIndex + 1,totalLen,col
   FROM CTE
   WHERE startIndex <= totalLen - @offset 
)
SELECT substring(col,startIndex, @offset) 
FROM CTE
WHERE startIndex > 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4896d1/2/0)**:

```
|     |
|-----|
| 094 |
| 947 |
| 474 |
| 740 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two possible options - a recursive CTE or a statement using a number table:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO StringTable
FROM (VALUES ('094740'), ('1237')) v (StringColumn)
```

Statement using a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @Length int = 3
;WITH rCTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Position, t.StringColumn
    FROM StringTable t   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Position + 1, r.StringColumn
    FROM rCTE r
    WHERE r.Position + @Length <= LEN(r.StringColumn)
)
SELECT StringColumn, SUBSTRING(StringColumn, Position, @Length) AS Substring
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY StringColumn, Position
```

Statement using a number table (with 1000 rows):

```
DECLARE @Length int = 3
;WITH NumberTable AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Rn
    FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) a (n)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) b (n)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) c (n)
)
SELECT t.StringColumn, SUBSTRING(t.StringColumn, n.Rn, @Length) AS Substring
FROM StringTable t
JOIN Numbertable n ON (n.Rn + @Length - 1) <= LEN(t.StringColumn)
ORDER BY t.StringColumn, n.Rn
```

Result:

```
StringColumn Substring
----------------------
094740       094
094740       947
094740       474
094740       740
1237         123
1237         237
```